# ansibleでreplaceの使用例の'\1'と'\2'はどういう意味でしょうか？

Tags: ansible

ansible公式サイトのreplaceモジュールの使用例の、
replaceキーの`\1`や`\2`は、どういう意味でしょうか？

#### 使用例

```
# Before 2.3, option 'dest', 'destfile' or 'name' was used instead of 'path'
- replace:
    path: /etc/hosts
    regexp: '(\s+)old\.host\.name(\s+.*)?$'
    replace: '\1new.host.name\2'
    backup: yes
```

#### 公式サイトの使用例

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/replace_module.html#examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

正規表現の**後方参照**と呼ばれるもので、`regexp:`キーの`()`で括られた部分の正規表現にマッチした値と順に置き換えられます。

```
regexp: '(\s+)old\.host\.name(\s+.*)?$'
```

1つ目の`()`にマッチした値が`\1`に、2つ目の`()`にマッチした値が`\2`に、以下開きカッコ`(`が増えるたびに`\n`の対応する数字も増えていきます。

Comment: なるほど。とても理解できました！
ありがとうございます。